# Spring context:component-scan fails to find components in another Eclipse project dependency referenced in POM

Tags: eclipse, spring, gwt, maven, m2eclipse

I am working on a GWT web application split across two Eclipse Projects (myclient & myservice).

The myclient project references the myservice project via a dependency in the POM.

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myservices</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The myclient project has a WAR directory src/main/webapp. The output folder for the myclient project is src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes.

The myclient project has a Spring descriptor application-context.xml with the following

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.myclient, com.myproject.myservices"/>
```

and the web.xml

```
<web-app>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener> 
...
</web-app>
```

I have several files in the myservices project annotated as spring @Component, @Service, @Configuration but these are not picked up by the component scan when I run the GWT application in Eclipse. As a test I experimented with placing an @Component in the myclient project and this was successfully created.

I believe the following log entry during application startup indicates the source of the problem

```
org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - Resolved location pattern [classpath*:com/myproject/myservices/**/*.class] to resources []
```

the location pattern for the myclient project resolves to all the resources on the classpath but for myservices no resources are found.

I experimented with building the myservices project JAR and placing this JAR into the src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib folder of the myclient project. When I do this the component scanning works. However for development I don't want to have to build and copy a JAR everytime I make changes to the myservices project. I imagine that the component scanning should work on a project referenced through the POM without having to the build that project but after much experimenting I have been unable to get this working.

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Comment: @abishkar Eclipse Helios

Answer (score 2):

Be sure that in the deployment assembly (right click your web project and select "deployment assembly" of your myclient project it is configured to deploy the jar that is outputted by the myservices project.  If you are using maven, the m2e, m2e-wtp project configurators should do this deployment assembly setup automatically.

Once you have deployment assembly settings properly configured, now when you deploy a project to your server using the Eclispe server adapter publish mechanism, everything should get deployed and the myservices jar would get placed in the right spot for your myclient project.

But make sure you the latest version of [m2e-wtp](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg03820.html) installed.  This way your configuration in your pom.xml and deployment assembly will get correctly configured.

Comment: Hi gamerson, thanks for your response. My project does not have the "deployment assembly" option. I think that is because it is a GWT project. I am using the maven m2e plugin and have tried updating to the latest version but that did not make a difference. Running a GWT app might be a little different to the Eclipse server adapter publish mechanism you are describing, as the GWT plugin runs the app out of eclipse in development mode using an embedded Jetty Web Server. I am not using m2e-wtp plugin - is this something that is required?

Comment: I see to get your myclient project to have "deployment assembly" it should be a webtools faceted project.  What is your pom package type for your myclient project?

Comment: If you have m2e-wtp plugin, it will convert all war package types to webtools faceted projects when you run "Maven > update project" or when you import the project using maven import project wizard.  Once this is a webtools faceted project, it will have the "deployment assembly" settings, that you can configure the proper deployment of the myservices jar.

Answer (score 2):

Try splitting your application-context.xml into 2 separate files:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>classpath:service-context.xml,classpath:client-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

myservices/src/main/resources/service-context.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.myservices"/>
```

myclient/src/main/resources/client-context.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject.myclient"/>
```

Comment: I have tried this but it was still unable to find the beans using component scan. If I declare the beans explicitly in Spring XML it finds them but not using component scan. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Have you tried adding your project as a build path dependency? (not a Maven dependency; "Build Path" -> "Projects" -> "Add")

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myproject"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following things:

1. Is your serviceproject present "only" as jar or is the whole project available via workspace resolution. This can be checked via maven-context-menue (Disable/Enable Workspaceresolution)
2. The layout of the webapp under src/main/webapp is okay. BUT do i get you right that all classes are copied there? If so, you should make sure everything is under target directory. So please check whether a maven call "clean package" generates a webappstructure under the target folder and all required libs (e.g. myservice) exist under *target\$your-webarchivename\WEB-INF\lib*

   1. Check that packaging in myservice pom.xml is set to jar (you probably have this, right?)

Answer (score 1):

it's obvious that your service jar is not included in your client project's build path. this is the only root cause.

Make sure 3 points:

1. you have run *mvn clean install* under your service project which has correct pom.xml.
2. you have run *mvn eclipse:eclipse* under your client project. this will pull out all your dependency project.
3. check your client eclipse project's build path dialog. is there your service jar in the list? **Make sure this**

Answer (score 0):

You better once look this tutorial
**http://fusesource.com/docs/framework/2.2/deploy_guide/CXFServletDeploySpring.html**